# Perform computation on a value in one row and update another row's column with that value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like :

```sh
Categor_1   Categor_2   Numeric_1   Numeric_2   Numeric_3  Numeric_col4   Month

ABC         XYZ          3523        454         4354       565      2018-02      
ABC         XYZ          333         444         123        565      2018-03 
qww         ggg          3222        568         123        483976      2018-03
```

I would like to apply some simple math on a column with a condition and assign it to a different row.

For instance 
if `Month == 2018-03 & Categor_2 == 'XYZ'`, perform `Numeric_3*2` and assign it to `Numeric_3` under month 2018-02.

So the output would be something like :

```sh
Categor_1  Categor_2  Numeric_1  Numeric_2  Numeric_3_ Adj Numeric_col4  Month 

ABC         XYZ          3523        454         246       565      2018-02      
ABC         XYZ          333         444         123        565      2018-03 
qww         ggg          3222        568         123        483976      2018-03
```

I was thinking of taking out the necessary columns, then doing a pivot, applying the math, then again reshaping it back in the orginal way.
However if there is a quick way, would be grateful to know

Answer (score 1):

It depends what is length of Series of filtered DataFrame - here is one element Series, so possible set to scalar by `next` with `iter` for posible add default value if condition not match:

```
mask = (df.Month == '2018-03') & (df.Categor_2 == 'XYZ')

print (df.loc[mask, 'Numeric_3'] * 3)
1    369
Name: Numeric_3, dtype: int64

#get first value of Series, if emty Series is returned 0
a = next(iter(df.loc[mask, 'Numeric_3'] * 3), 0)
print (a)
369

df.loc[df.Month == '2018-02', 'Numeric_3'] = a
print (df)
  Categor_1 Categor_2  Numeric_1  Numeric_2  Numeric_3  Numeric_col4    Month
0       ABC       XYZ       3523        454        369           565  2018-02
1       ABC       XYZ        333        444        123           565  2018-03
2       qww       ggg       3222        568        123        483976  2018-03
```

Comment: One element Series as in ? You mean because its just one column we are modifying (Numeric_3), it is one element series ?

Comment: Yes, I think `df.loc[mask, 'Numeric_3']`

Comment: the dataframe in reality has multiple categorical columns and multiple numerical columns..the shape of the df would be approx 100000*100, with the the filter condition being applied on approx 20000 rows..
the Month.value_counts() is also 4

Comment: @asimo - So not sure if can help you. Problem is need update value in another row by condition, here second row by first. If need set scalar like in my answer it working, but general solution is really dependent of data.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, i'll take a look.
Would there be another approach ?

Comment: @asimo - hmmm, what is wrongby my approach? Can you explain more?